# TcpClient updates once and then stuck listening

Tags: c#, tcp, xna

I'm doing an XNA game which is client-server based, and I have some difficulties integrating a `Message Framing` mechanism into the networking part.

This is the message framing protocol class I've gotten from [here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/sample-code-length-prefix-message.html), with slight refactoring:

```
using System;

namespace XnaCommonLib.Network
{
    // Original source: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/sample-code-length-prefix-message.html
    /// <summary>
    /// Maintains the necessary buffers for applying a length-prefix message framing protocol over a stream.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// <para>Create one instance of this class for each incoming stream, and assign a handler to <see cref="MessageArrived"/>. As bytes arrive at the stream, pass them to <see cref="DataReceived"/>, which will invoke <see cref="MessageArrived"/> as necessary.</para>
    /// <para>If <see cref="DataReceived"/> raises <see cref="System.Net.ProtocolViolationException"/>, then the stream data should be considered invalid. After that point, no methods should be called on that <see cref="PacketProtocol"/> instance.</para>
    /// <para>This class uses a 4-byte signed integer length prefix, which allows for message sizes up to 2 GB. Keepalive messages are supported as messages with a length prefix of 0 and no message data.</para>
    /// <para>This is EXAMPLE CODE! It is not particularly efficient; in particular, if this class is rewritten so that a particular interface is used (e.g., Socket's IAsyncResult methods), some buffer copies become unnecessary and may be removed.</para>
    /// </remarks>
    public class PacketProtocol
    {
        private const int LengthBufferSize = sizeof(int);

        /// <summary>
        /// Wraps a message. The wrapped message is ready to send to a stream.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// <para>Generates a length prefix for the message and returns the combined length prefix and message.</para>
        /// </remarks>
        /// <param name="message">The message to send.</param>
        public static byte[] WrapMessage(byte[] message)
        {
            // Get the length prefix for the message
            var lengthPrefix = BitConverter.GetBytes(message.Length);

            // Concatenate the length prefix and the message
            var ret = new byte[lengthPrefix.Length + message.Length];
            lengthPrefix.CopyTo(ret, 0);
            message.CopyTo(ret, lengthPrefix.Length);

            return ret;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Wraps a keepalive (0-length) message. The wrapped message is ready to send to a stream.
        /// </summary>
        public static byte[] WrapKeepaliveMessage()
        {
            return BitConverter.GetBytes(0);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new <see cref="PacketProtocol"/>, limiting message sizes to the given maximum size.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="maxMessageBufferSize">The maximum message size supported by this protocol. This may be less than or equal to zero to indicate no maximum message size.</param>
        public PacketProtocol(int maxMessageBufferSize)
        {
            // We allocate the buffer for receiving message lengths immediately
            lengthBuffer = new byte[LengthBufferSize];
            maxMessageSize = maxMessageBufferSize;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The buffer for the length prefix; this is always 4 bytes long.
        /// </summary>
        private readonly byte[] lengthBuffer;

        /// <summary>
        /// The buffer for the data; this is null if we are receiving the length prefix buffer.
        /// </summary>
        private byte[] dataBuffer;

        /// <summary>
        /// The number of bytes already read into the buffer (the length buffer if <see cref="dataBuffer"/> is null, otherwise the data buffer).
        /// </summary>
        private int bytesReceived;

        /// <summary>
        /// The maximum size of messages allowed.
        /// </summary>
        private readonly int maxMessageSize;

        /// <summary>
        /// Indicates the completion of a message read from the stream.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// <para>This may be called with an empty message, indicating that the other end had sent a keepalive message. This will never be called with a null message.</para>
        /// <para>This event is invoked from within a call to <see cref="DataReceived"/>. Handlers for this event should not call <see cref="DataReceived"/>.</para>
        /// </remarks>
        public Action<byte[]> MessageArrived
        {
            get; set;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Notifies the <see cref="PacketProtocol"/> instance that incoming data has been received from the stream. This method will invoke <see cref="MessageArrived"/> as necessary.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// <para>This method may invoke <see cref="MessageArrived"/> zero or more times.</para>
        /// <para>Zero-length receives are ignored. Many streams use a 0-length read to indicate the end of a stream, but <see cref="PacketProtocol"/> takes no action in this case.</para>
        /// </remarks>
        /// <param name="data">The data received from the stream. Cannot be null.</param>
        /// <exception cref="System.Net.ProtocolViolationException">If the data received is not a properly-formed message.</exception>
        public void DataReceived(byte[] data)
        {
            // Process the incoming data in chunks, as the ReadCompleted requests it

            // Logically, we are satisfying read requests with the received data, instead of processing the
            //  incoming buffer looking for messages.

            var i = 0;
            while (i != data.Length)
            {
                // Determine how many bytes we want to transfer to the buffer and transfer them
                var bytesAvailable = data.Length - i;
                if (dataBuffer != null)
                {
                    // We're reading into the data buffer
                    var bytesRequested = dataBuffer.Length - bytesReceived;

                    // Copy the incoming bytes into the buffer
                    var bytesTransferred = Math.Min(bytesRequested, bytesAvailable);
                    Array.Copy(data, i, dataBuffer, bytesReceived, bytesTransferred);
                    i += bytesTransferred;

                    // Notify "read completion"
                    ReadCompleted(bytesTransferred);
                }
                else
                {
                    // We're reading into the length prefix buffer
                    var bytesRequested = lengthBuffer.Length - bytesReceived;

                    // Copy the incoming bytes into the buffer
                    var bytesTransferred = Math.Min(bytesRequested, bytesAvailable);
                    Array.Copy(data, i, lengthBuffer, bytesReceived, bytesTransferred);
                    i += bytesTransferred;

                    // Notify "read completion"
                    ReadCompleted(bytesTransferred);
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Called when a read completes. Parses the received data and calls <see cref="MessageArrived"/> if necessary.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="count">The number of bytes read.</param>
        /// <exception cref="System.Net.ProtocolViolationException">If the data received is not a properly-formed message.</exception>
        private void ReadCompleted(int count)
        {
            // Get the number of bytes read into the buffer
            bytesReceived += count;

            if (dataBuffer == null)
            {
                // We're currently receiving the length buffer

                if (bytesReceived != LengthBufferSize)
                {
                    // We haven't gotten all the length buffer yet: just wait for more data to arrive
                }
                else
                {
                    // We've gotten the length buffer
                    var length = BitConverter.ToInt32(lengthBuffer, 0);

                    // Sanity check for length < 0
                    if (length < 0)
                        throw new System.Net.ProtocolViolationException("Message length is less than zero");

                    // Another sanity check is needed here for very large packets, to prevent denial-of-service attacks
                    if (maxMessageSize > 0 && length > maxMessageSize)
                        throw new System.Net.ProtocolViolationException("Message length " + length.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " is larger than maximum message size " + maxMessageSize.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

                    // Zero-length packets are allowed as keepalives
                    if (length == 0)
                    {
                        bytesReceived = 0;
                        MessageArrived?.Invoke(new byte[0]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Create the data buffer and start reading into it
                        dataBuffer = new byte[length];
                        bytesReceived = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (bytesReceived != dataBuffer.Length)
                    // We haven't gotten all the data buffer yet: just wait for more data to arrive
                    return;

                // We've gotten an entire packet
                MessageArrived?.Invoke(dataBuffer);

                // Start reading the length buffer again
                dataBuffer = null;
                bytesReceived = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've debugged the code, and it seems to function properly. The problem though is how I use this code. From what I understand, I need to call `PacketProtocol::DataReceived` every time I receive data. But from my point of view, as I'm using TCP, it was quite hard to understand what exactly counts as `Data Received`, as `TCP` uses a `Stream`, whereas `UDP` for example, uses datagrams, so the definition of `DataReceived` is quite hard for me to define for `TCP`.

I've tried using the following helper method to get it to work:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace XnaCommonLib.Network
{
    public static class HelperMethods
    {
        public static void Receive(TcpClient connection, BinaryReader reader, PacketProtocol packetProtocol)
        {
            var buffer = new byte[connection.ReceiveBufferSize];

            while (reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) > 0) // this is where it gets stuck
            {
                packetProtocol.DataReceived(buffer);
                buffer = new byte[connection.ReceiveBufferSize];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The usage of this method is as follows:

**ConnectionHandler** - client side network management class

```
private void ConnectionHandler_InteractWithServer()
{
    while (Connection.Connected)
    {
        try
        {
            HelperMethods.Receive(Connection, Reader, PacketProtocol);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Connection.Close();
            break;
        }

        Thread.Sleep(Constants.Time.UpdateThreadSleepTime);
    }
}
```

This method is called in a thread, so it runs constantly.
The client side callback of PacketProtocol is this:

```
private void PacketProtocol_MessageRecievedCallback(byte[] data)
{
    if (data.Length == 0)
        return;

    var stringData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
    ProcessServerUpdate(stringData);
    WritePlayerData();
}

private void ProcessServerUpdate(string message)
{
    UpdatePing();

    var incomingUpdate = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServerToClientUpdateMessage>(message);
    EmsServerEndpoint.BroadcastIncomingEvents(incomingUpdate.Broadcasts);

    foreach (var update in incomingUpdate.PlayerUpdates)
        ApplyUpdate(update);
}

private void ApplyUpdate(PlayerUpdate update)
{
    var entity = new Entity(update.Guid);
    if (!ClientGameManager.EntityPool.Exists(entity))
    {
        var newGo = ClientGameManager.BeginAllocateRemote(entity.Id);
        newGo.Components.Get<NetworkPlayer>().Update(update);
        ClientGameManager.EndAllocate(newGo);
    }
    else
    {
        var remoteComponents = ClientGameManager.EntityPool.GetComponents(entity);
        remoteComponents.Get<NetworkPlayer>().Update(update);
    }
}

private void WritePlayerData()
{
    var message = new ClientToServerUpdateMessage
    {
        Broadcasts = EmsServerEndpoint.Flush(),
        PlayerUpdate = new PlayerUpdate(GameObject.Components)
    };

    var messageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message));
    var wrapperMessage = PacketProtocol.WrapMessage(messageBytes);
    Writer.Write(wrapperMessage);
}
```

It's the callback method alongside the methods called by it.

This is the server's callback for the PacketProtocol:

```
private void PacketProtocol_MessageArrivedCallback(byte[] bytes)
{
    if (bytes.Length == 0)
        return;

    var stringData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
    ProcessClientUpdate(stringData);
    SendServerUpdate();
}

private void SendServerUpdate()
{
    var message = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new ServerToClientUpdateMessage
    {
        Broadcasts = EmsServerEndpoint.Flush(),
        PlayerUpdates = PlayerUpdates()
    });

    var messageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
    Writer.Write(PacketProtocol.WrapMessage(messageBytes));
}

private void ProcessClientUpdate(string clientMessageString)
{
    var clientMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClientToServerUpdateMessage>(clientMessageString);
    EmsServerEndpoint.BroadcastIncomingEvents(clientMessage.Broadcasts);
    UpdateClient(clientMessage.PlayerUpdate);
}

private IList<PlayerUpdate> PlayerUpdates()
{
    return GameManager.EntityPool.AllThat(PlayerUpdate.IsPlayer).Select(c => new PlayerUpdate(c)).ToList();
}

private void UpdateClient(PlayerUpdate playerUpdate)
{
    var components = GameObject.Components;
    components.Get<DirectionalInput>().Update(playerUpdate.Input);
}
```

---

So now for the actual problem: The code works normally for the first update - The message is received properly and the update occurs. Whereas after that, both the client and the server get stuck in the `while (reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) > 0)` line.

To begin the actual communication, this is what `ConnectionHandler` does:

```
WriteLoginDataToServer(name, team);
ReadLoginResponseFromServer();
WritePlayerData();
UpdateThread.Start();
```

Before starting the update thread (that runs the communication loop with the server), it calls `WritePlayerData`, which send the initial update to the server. I would suppose that that would make him call `SendServerUpdate`, and the client would pick it up and the loop would continue, but it doesn't happen.

Comment: The line where it get's stuck it's a blocking method, if there's not enough data to read (buffer.length) it won't return, but that might not be the problem. Also, to me your code seems a litle messy: `Something`->`ConnectionHandler_InteractWithServer()`->`HelperMethods`->`PacketProtocol`. Too much depth just to receive data.

Comment: `PacketProtocol` takes a callback to call when it receives a message, and so I give it a callback method that converts the received `byte[]` to a string and Deserializes the string to an object (I work with jsons). `ConnectionHandler_InteractWithServer()` is a thread method, meaning that its called once and runs in a loop until a disconnect happens. I moved the `Receive` method to an outer utility class because its logic is common to both the client and the server side. I think that's hardly adding up and depth.

Comment: Well, maybe it's not that bad, the comments on the PacketProtocol  make it look really ugly and hard to read though. About the `DataReceived` definition: it depends about how you implement it. Here, when sending at least, it's done by creating a prefix for each "message" which contains the length (`length:message`), this way it's easy to identify each message, every time you receive a `prefix` you read `length` bytes and process that message, then repeat. This way avoids a fixed length message and buffer. For some reason this isn't done when reciving, the buffer size it's fixed to 8192bytes.

Comment: You understood me wrong. I know everything that's going on inside `PacketProtocol`. It works very nicely, and it is not the problematic class. 
By `definition of DataReceived`, I mean - When exactly is data received? in `UDP`, it's when a `Datagram` is received. In TCP, Streams are used, so you can't exactly pinpoint when bytes are added to the stream, and exactly how much bytes were added, which is basically everything that receiving a message stands for. This is the problematic part is for me, and this is why the `while` loop in `Receive` is the problem

Comment: Data is received when it has been transfered, it can be 1 byte or 30 and it can contain 1 or 30 "messages", this happens Since TCP works as a Stream of data, so you have to decide what is a individual "datagram"/"message" you can do this in many different ways, but you have to separate each one. You can't know when data is added, but you can see how much data can be read by socket.Avaliable. I think you code doesn't work properly because there isn't a way to tell each "message" apart. English is not my main language and I don't explain myself very well, so sorry about that.

Comment: The PacketProtocol separates messages apart, it's for certain. I might change the while to available, and replace the `while (Read ...)` with `Reader.ReadBytes(Socket.Available)` or something. I'll check it out. Thank you!

Comment: If you do that it'll just read x bytes when that amount is available, try doing something like `while(true) { if(socket.Avaiable>=32){ Read..} Thread.Sleep(x);  }`. I'll add an anwser about how I would approach this. The `SocketProtocol` doesn't feel right to me. (Doesn't mean it's bad code)

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace XnaCommonLib.Network
{
    public static class HelperMethods
    {
        public static void Receive(TcpClient connection, BinaryReader reader, PacketProtocol packetProtocol)
        {
            var bufferSize = connection.Available;
            var buffer = reader.ReadBytes(bufferSize);
            packetProtocol.DataReceived(buffer); 
        }
    }
}
```

This is what `Receive` looks now, and it works. Thanks to the `null` dude in the comments!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would approach receiving messages:

A class to receive the data:

```
class DataReceiver
{    
 public Delegate MessageReceived(string message);
 pulic MessageReceived MessageReceivedEvent;

 private void Socket;
 private bool IsReceiving;
 public Class DataReceiver(Socket sock)
 {
 Socket = sock;
 }
 public void StartReceiving()
  => Task.Run((Action)ReceiveLoop);
 public void StopReceiving()
  => IsReceiving = false;

 private void ReceiveLoop()
 {
  IsReceiving = true;
  while(IsReceiving)
  {
   byte[] LengthHeader = new byte[4];
   Socket.Receive(LenthHeader, 0, 4);
   byte[] Buffer = new byte[BitConverter.ToInt32(LengthHeader);
   Socket.Receive(Buffer, 0,Buffer.Length);
   MessageReceivedEvent?.Invoke(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Buffer);
  }
 }          
}
```

Instead of accumulating bytes until a message is completed you receive a `header` that contains the length of the message, then receive that message fully. Then this is converted to a string and you can handle it by `MessageReceivedEvent`.

To send data you use this function:

```
public void Send(string message, Socket sock)
{
  byte[] LengthHeader;
  byte[] Buffer;
  Buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
  LengthHeader = BitConverter.GetBytes(Buffer.Length);
  sock.Send(LengthHeader, 0, 4);
  socket.Send(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length;
}
```

You have to implement this on both client and server, and simplifies message receiving/sending, you just have to Serialize to send, and deserialize to receive.